# PHP hierarchy Tree

Tags: php, arrays

[image][image]

I having a problem for getting sub account, I wanted to list down all sub account inside array for example

id = 1, then sub id will be

```
[0] = 2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
[1] = 3,11,12,13
```

when id = 2

```
[0] = 4,6
[1] = 5,7,9,10,8
```

Please guide me how to do that, Appreciate that if you could guide me.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish, please edit your question to state the desired action, what you have already tried/done and give information on the project you are working on before we can help

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the data from? An Database? Directly as an Array? As an JSON String? And i don't understand your field "sub_id". It seems always to be the same value as the id, except the records with the ids 12,13,14. That's not clear.